# Ansible and inventory specific vars

Tags: ansible

Is it possible to declare variables the inventory level? For example I have a inventory for my development env, and another one for my production env.

I have templates that I need populated with certain variables that are specific to either environment.

At the moment it seems I can only set these variables at the group or host level, but I want it to apply for the entire inventory to avoid repeating myself for each group or host I have defined!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It turns out, my previous answer was not so right. There is an easier solution. Just define the vars for the `all` group. I would have expected ansible complaining there is no matching group definition, but it works, I just tested it:

```
[some_group]
some_host

[another_group]
another_host

[all:vars]
some_var=some_value
```

But in this case you really are forced to define the vars **in** the inventory file and can not define it in `group_vars/all`, but this should be obvious.

Answer (score 3):

**Leaving this here for reference, but check out my other answer, there is a simpler way to do it.**

---

I believe this is not directly possible. You can define variables directly **in** the inventory, but they still have to be defined per [host](http://docs.ansible.com/intro_inventory.html#host-variables) or [group](http://docs.ansible.com/intro_inventory.html#group-variables).

You could create a group which inherits from all other groups of that inventory file and then assign the variables to this group.

Inventory file `myInventory`:

```
[some_group]
some_host

[another_group]
another_host

[myInventory:children]
some_group
another_group

[myInventory:vars]
some_var=some_value
```

Comment: This is currently the solution I'm using. Just doesn't seem clean to me, since now I need to remember to add any new groups to this `children` group. Hopefully Ansible addresses this in upcoming release.

Comment: I agree, that is error prone. I just tested something and it works. Check out my other answer, which is a way easier solution.

Answer (score 1):

Separate inventories are a very good idea. The above answer's fully accurate, but I don't believe you'll be able to follow that approach if your groups are split up across inventory files, which I think your question implies they are.

Depending on your platform (the mode being AWS), it's effortless to group all your machines by environment, and it doesn't matter which inventory or inventories pick them up. **I would just add an environment group variable file.**

Please edit if `group_vars` are something you're trying to avoid categorically. If that's the case, then appropriate or create your own inventory scripts (adding a constant variable to the *ec2* one is very very easy).